# EnterCriticalSection and CRITICAL_SECTION on windows

Tags: windows, critical-section

In my const' - I want that 'secondCommand' will be called only after 'firstCommand'. I tried to work with EnterCriticalSection, but the problem is, where to initiate my lock - 
If I do it in the constructor (at #), and release the lock after 'firstCommand'( at ##), and try to acquire the lock again before 'secondCommand' (at ###), it might not work since at ###, even if the lock is locked - secondCommand can still be called - since the the locking accured in the same thead (it is just like calling two times in a row "lock" and "lock" - there will not be a deadlock).

on the other hand, If I lock right before 'firstCommand' (at ####) and release right after 'firstCommand' (at ##), when checking if the lock is locked - the lock can uninitialized - which will cause a problem. here is my code:

```
myClass::myClass (){
    #
    threadFunction();
    ###
    secondCommand();
}

void myClass::threadFunction(){
    DWORD threadID;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc,0, 0, &threadID);
}

threadFunc(){
    ####
    firstCommand();
    ##
    while(true){};
}
```

It seems like an easy problem, but I've been tring to solve it for an hour now.Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off using an event: look at [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You would create the event in the constructor, wait for it at "###", and set it at "##". And you should probably check the return value of WaitForSingleObject; it will be WAIT_OBJECT_0 if successful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the nature of your problem is not as simple as the example you posted, but one obvious way is just to do this

```cpp
myClass::myClass (){
    firstCommand();
    threadFunction();
    secondCommand();
}

void myClass::threadFunction(){
    DWORD threadID;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc,0, 0, &threadID);
}

threadFunc(){
    while(true){};
}
```

Is there some reason that `firstCommand` has to run on another thread?

**EDIT**
As you need to run `firstCommand` on the background thread, then use an event to signal when it's safe. So in `myClass` define a member variable (or somewhere accessible to both threads) for an event handle

```cpp
HANDLE m_hEvent;
```

and use it like so

```cpp
myClass::myClass (){
    m_hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    threadFunction();
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hEvent, INFINITE);
    secondCommand();
    CloseHandle(m_hEvent);
    m_hEvent = NULL;
}

void myClass::threadFunction(){
    DWORD threadID;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc,0, 0, &threadID);
}

threadFunc(){
    firstCommand();
    SetEvent(m_hEvent);
    while(true){};
}
```

So, in the main thread, `secondCommand` waits for the event to be signalled before running. In the worker thread, the event is set (signalled) after `firstCommand` has completed.

Comment: @kakush - fair enough - I've edited my answer to show how to do this using a Windows event object.